# SyntaxError: unexpected token 'print'

Tags: python, ironpython

The following code runs fine in IDLE [2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:03:49) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]]:

```
x = 5
if True:
   pass
   x=6
else:
   x=7
print x
```

But in IronPython ['2.7.3 (IronPython 2.7.3 (2.7.0.40) on .NET 4.0.30319.34014 (64-bit))], the last line gives a `SyntaxError: unexpected token 'print'`

I copied and pasted the same lines of text in both systems, so they should be the same, including any invisible characters.

What could be the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quirk of the interactive interpreter, and has nothing to do with Ironpython vs regular Python. If you save your code in a file and run it, it will work with any Python.

Here is a shorter example that shows the error:

```
>>> if False:
...      pass
... pass
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    pass
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

When using the interactive interpreter, you must end a multi-line statement with an empty line, as so:

```
>>> if False:
...     pass
... 
>>> pass
>>>
```

Comment: Yes.  If in the console I manually press Enter to get an extra blank line, I can add print x. But if I copy and paste text containing a blank line followed by print x, the same error is there.

Answer (score 4):

If you have it on a Microsoft Visual Studio, then it seems that you have to have any `print` commands in `()`.
So, for example:

```
print (dictionary_name['notreal'])
```

or

```
print (x)
```

Comment: I think that is the Python 3 `print` syntax.

Comment: Just pointed that out because the VS translator for Python gives the same exact error for not putting those in...

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing python in VS code, always remind yourself to put bracket for print command.
print(). It should be worked!